# Why don't iperf, scamper and path MTU discovery packet captures agree on the path's MTU?

Tags: routing, ipv4

Let's do some path MTU discovery between two Debian hosts separated by a Debian router that runs Shorewall-generated iptables rules. Each of the two hosts uses a single Ethernet link while the router uses tagged VLANs over two aggregated Ethernet links.

Using [scamper](http://www.caida.org/tools/measurement/scamper/) :

```
root@kitandara:/home/jm# scamper -I "trace -M 10.64.0.2"
traceroute from 10.1.0.5 to 10.64.0.2
 1  10.1.0.1  0.180 ms [mtu: 6128]
 2  10.64.0.2  0.243 ms [mtu: 6128]
```

Good: 6128 bytes is the expected result (cheap Realtek Ethernet adapters can't handle jumbo frames of a decent size).

Now, let [iperf](http://iperf.fr/) perform a throughput test and tell us about the MTU by the way :

```
root@kitandara:/home/jm# iperf -c 10.64.0.2 -N -m
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 10.64.0.2, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 66.2 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 10.1.0.5 port 59828 connected with 10.64.0.2 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  1011 MBytes   848 Mbits/sec
[  3] MSS size 6076 bytes (MTU 6116 bytes, unknown interface)
```

6116 bytes ? Why ?

And now for something completely different, let's see what this session's traffic actually contained :

```
root@kitandara:/home/jm# tshark -i eth0 -R "(ip.dst == 10.64.0.2) || (ip.src == 10.64.0.2)" | head
Capturing on eth0
  1.308557     10.1.0.5 -> 10.64.0.2    TCP 74 60310 > 5001 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5340 Len=0 MSS=534 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=101928961 TSecr=0 WS=16
  1.308801    10.64.0.2 -> 10.1.0.5     TCP 74 5001 > 60310 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=18328 Len=0 MSS=6088 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=3764064056 TSecr=101928961 WS=64
```

6088 bytes MSS, which means a 6128 MTU... Good. But then why does iperf announce a 6116 bytes MTU ?

At that point thoroughness calls for a closer look at what happens during the scamper trace session :

```
root@kitandara:/home/jm# tshark -i eth0 -R "(ip.dst == 10.64.0.2) || (ip.src == 10.64.0.2)"
Capturing on eth0
  0.000000     10.1.0.5 -> 10.64.0.2    UDP 58 Source port: 43870  Destination port: 33435
  0.000175     10.1.0.1 -> 10.1.0.5     ICMP 86 Time-to-live exceeded (Time to live exceeded in transit)
  0.050358     10.1.0.5 -> 10.64.0.2    UDP 58 Source port: 43870  Destination port: 33436
  0.050592    10.64.0.2 -> 10.1.0.5     ICMP 86 Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
  0.099790     10.1.0.5 -> 10.64.0.2    UDP 6142 Source port: 43870  Destination port: 33437
  0.100912    10.64.0.2 -> 10.1.0.5     ICMP 590 Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)
```

All those packets have a udp.length of 24 except the two last which have a udp.length of 6108... But then how does scamper tell us that the path MTU is 6128 ?

6108, 6116, 6128... So many MTU to choose from !

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Very interesting.

MSS (maximum segment size) = MTU - IP header = 6076.

6076 + 40 = 6116.

Could it be Debian is using the IP options fields in the IP header? That might be the extra 12 bytes...

Comment: Is it possible that the TCP handshake establishes a 6128 bytes MTU and then iperf finds out that he failed to transmit more than 6116 bytes at a time - which would be a sort of empirical MTU unrelated to the "official" one ?

Comment: Whatever the IP options, isn't there a padding that ensures that length(IP options + padding) = 32 bits ?

Comment: 12 bytes… Didn't you mean "TCP options" instead of "IP options" ?

Comment: I sampled the TCP options of the iperf session : apparently always 12 bytes (only the timestamps)

Comment: So, the best hypothesis so far : the TCP options reduce the payload that iperf gets across and iperf reports that as a reduced MTU, which is incorrect because it is merely a reduced payload and not an actually lower MTU. I'll have to check that with someone who knows iperf - or dive in myself.

That leaves the MTU vs. udp.length discrepancy - that may have something to do with scamper's trace type option...

Comment: In github.com/jasonrm/iperf/blob/… a comment says "// keep track of read sizes -> gives some indication of MTU size" and in github.com/jasonrm/iperf/blob/… another one says "Report the MSS and MTU, given the MSS (or a guess thereof)" - strange considering that iperf is supposed to support actual Path MTU Discovery.

Answer (score 3):

tshark is reporting the ethernet frame size: 6142 - 14 (ethernet header) = 6128 IP bytes.

scamper does a traceroute with small packets before probing with large packets for MTU discovery (that is why you see small packets followed by a large one).  this is useful to distinguish between all packets being discarded / unresponsive and just the big ones.

https://www.usenix.org/conference/imc-05/inferring-and-debugging-path-mtu-discovery-failures